# Spring Data Mongo Db transactional annotation error handling of TransientTransactionError

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have multiple operations on Mongo which I want to be considered as one operation so I enabled transactions. I'm using Mongo version 5.

The configuration class contains the following bean definition:

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
    return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
}
```

My business logic is similar to below snippet. Assume inside this method there are changes done on different collections.

```
@Transactional
public MyResult create(String payload) {
    //operations omitted for brevity
}
```

Based on the Mongo documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/core/transactions/) I quote:

> The new callback API also incorporates retry logic for TransientTransactionError or UnknownTransactionCommitResult commit errors.

Also this as reference: https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/transactions/transactions.rst#error-labels

Does Spring data Mongo db know how to handle the TransientTransactionError (including the retry described in the docs)? If not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this issue when my tx structure looks like the following:
[image]

And, it seems to just throw exception when used with Spring Reactive Mongo Transaction (because the API that I use seems to use [the Core API](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/mongodb-transactions#how-do-you-use-transactions)).

So, you might need to check the library's internal whether it's using Core or Callback API.